# Set Identification from Garage Sale Score

Tags: set-identification, star-wars, racers

Sorry for the immediate request upon joining, but you guys all seem so knowledgeable that it might save me a bunch of searching!

We picked up some used and (mostly) built LEGO, and I'd like to try and find all the instructions that might be available before I tear them apart into pieces. My son is still pretty new to the LEGO world, so he likes to have the specific instructions and hasn't quite hit the "use your imagination and build whatever you want" phase.

If you have a few moments to delve into set identification, I'd really appreciate the help! I have about [15 things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3KIg.jpg)!, but I recognise that this is a ton to ask for! But, if you know what this F1-type car is, my son wants to try building it first!

[image: F1 Car]

Comment: Howdy. Welcome to Bricks.  It would probably be better to split this up into a few posts.  Asking for a 2-3 identifications in a post is totally acceptable, but asking for 15 at once is probably too many at once.  It would also be great if you could inline a couple of images per post rather than linking to a gallery.

Comment: Totally understandable! I was thinking that seeing a bunch might allow someone to recognize something quickly, but now that you mention it - it does seem a bit unreasonable! I'll reformat things. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Responding to the [gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3KIg.jpg) from the original question:

Photo #1

[7124-1: Flash Speeder](https://brickset.com/sets/7124-1/Flash-Speeder)

Photo #2

[7316-1: Excavation Searcher](https://brickset.com/sets/7316-1/Excavation-Searcher)

Photo # 3

[8644-1 Street Maniac](http://8644-1:%20Street%20Maniac)

Photo #4

[4743-1: Ice Blade](https://brickset.com/sets/4743-1/Ice-Blade)

Photo #5

[8650-1 : Furious Slammer Racer](https://brickset.com/sets/8650-1/Furious-Slammer-Racer)

Photo #6

[8356-1 # Jungle Monster](https://brickset.com/sets/8356-1/Jungle-Monster)

Photo #7

[4743-1: Ice Blade](https://brickset.com/sets/4743-1/Ice-Blade)

Photo #8

[7315-1: Solar Explorer](https://brickset.com/sets/7315-1/Solar-Explorer)

Photo #9

[4098-1: High Flyers](https://brickset.com/sets/4098-1/High-Flyers)

Photo #10

don't know

Photo #9

[8643-1: Power Cruiser](https://brickset.com/sets/8643-1/Power-Cruiser)

Photo #11

[7314: Recon Mech RP](https://brickset.com/sets/7314-1/Recon-Mech-RP)

Photo #12

[7315-1: Solar Explorer](https://brickset.com/sets/7315-1/Solar-Explorer)

Photo #13

[7141-1:    Naboo Fighter](https://brickset.com/sets/7141-1/Naboo-Fighter)

Photo #14

[6616-1: Rocket-Dragster](https://brickset.com/sets/6616-1/Rocket-Dragster)

Photo #15

[4587-1: Duel-Racers](https://brickset.com/sets/4587-1/Duel-Racers)

Photo #16

[7313: Red Planet Protector](https://brickset.com/sets/7313-1/Red-Planet-Protector)

Photo #17

[7316-1: Excavation Searcher](https://brickset.com/sets/7316-1/Excavation-Searcher)

Photo #18
[7312-1: T-3 Trike](https://brickset.com/sets/7312-1/T-3-Trike)

Photo #19

[8650-1 : Furious Slammer Race](https://brickset.com/sets/8650-1/Furious-Slammer-Racer)r

Photo #20

don't know

---

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a wonderful start and I really appreciate the time.

Comment: That's a great answer.  Sorry for messing up the question so it doesn't fit any longer.  Hopefully I fixed the answer to your liking.

Comment: It really is a great answer!  I have a very excited kiddo, so thank you again Syberion. We've already put the little Racer Power Cruisers together thanks to your help.

Comment: It appears that 10 and 20 are not from a set, but rather self-built. It might help to provide multiple views for those.

Answer (score 0):

## 20 appears to be an assortment of parts from this power racers collection, with several additions that are not part of the set.

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?S=8383-1&in=S